# My Lifecam HD-300 is not recognized

Tags: usb

I am using VMWare 15.0.4 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Cheese, VLC and Skype can not find my WEBCAM.  Can you give me a step by step procedure to have my webcam works properly.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your Webcam is controlled by the VM Host, not the Guest. You must change the VMWare settings for the Guest to see host devices. Seems like a VMWare question more than an Ubuntu question...but the question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly. 
Do you run your Ubuntu 20.04 in VMWare 15.0.4?

If yes, you have to tell your VM, that you want to add an generic usb device. For more information see the link below.

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_devices_usb_connect.html